# Rename image files in a folder with SchoolId resulted from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to rename image files with schoolId in [school] table. Is there any other approach to do this. [image: Folder with school images]
Currently, i am doing following steps for each file:
 1. copy image file name
 2. use this query to get schoolId

```
SELECT * FROM [School]  
where SchoolCDS='01611926000962
```

[image: School Table]

3. Rename image file with SchoolId

Any best approach?

Answer (score 0):

have you stored image file name?
if yes,
then fetch the image file name from db, then fetch school id from db based on file name, finally update db with new file name.

if no, (in case of physical stored image)

get file name as given below:

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;
result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

rest code is same as above.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your response. but i got error. string datatype is not defined in sql server 2008.

Comment: Its c# code. you can't access physical stored image from sql. you have to get it from front end and then send its name as parameter to your sql query or stored procedure

Comment: Ok. Thanks. but i want to do this using SQL server 2008.